# Update and Remove a Single event of the calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to edit/remove a single event of the callendar, but with my current code, the update/remove afects all events inside the calendar.

#### Update Attempt:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var evento = $('#calendario').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event){
       return event.className == 8;
    });        
    evento[0].backgroundColor = "red";
    $('#calendario').fullCalendar('updateEvent', evento[0]);  
});
```

It changes the background color of all events. Also, it changes the events `title`, all to the same (The one with that `ClassName`).

#### Remove Attempt:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   $('#calendario').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(event){
      return event.className = 8;
   });
});
```

Also, this method removes ALL events.

How may I target a single event ?

**UPDATE**

Just found the problem:
Even if I target only that specific `event` with that specific `className`, this method `updateEvent`, will update ALL EVENTS THAT SHARE THE SAME `ID`.  Why?
I don't think it's supposed to happen.

Comment: Could you add the rest of your JavaScript, I tried using your update code in my application and it worked. I have added an answer below for the removing.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that you should be able to target events using a filter.

When you attempt to remove the event you are using the assignment operator rather than the equals operator. By changing that, your filter should then return true for removing the event with that class.

The following code worked for adding a class to one event and then removing the event using the class.

```
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            if (event.id === 628) {
                event.className = "Test";
            }

        },
        eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (event) {
                return event.className === "Test";
            });
        }
```